# Posting nsnotification but observer is not hearing it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I am using NSNotifiationCenter, like a 1000 other times, and post a notification, but my observers are not hearing it?  What gives?

=== THIS IS IN MY TABLEVIEW ===

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleSuccessSocket)
                                             name:kNotificationServiceStartSuccessful
                                           object:self];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleFailedSocketConnection)
                                             name:kNotificationSocketFailedToConnect
                                           object:self];
}
```

=== THIS IS IN MY SOCKETMANAGER (socket manager is a singleton if that matters) ===

```
-(void)willStartService {

....

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationServiceStartSuccessful object:nil];

....

}
```

I have debugged and viewDidLoad is being called in my view. Yes, my willStartService is being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the TableView only for notifications sent by itself. It should be..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(handleSuccessSocket)
                                         name:kNotificationServiceStartSuccessful
                                       object:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `object:nil` in your `-addObserver:selector:name:object` method calls. What you're doing is telling Notification Center to *ONLY* listen for notifications that come from the table view instance.

If you don't want to pass `nil` you'll have to pass an instance of your socket manager.

Check the Docs:
[https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver%3aselector%3aname%3aobject):